# Is there a balance of colours between the heart symbol and the brand name in this logo?

Tags: color, logo, critique

I would like to know whether this logo is balanced between the name of the brand and the symbol? The decision was to divide the word *Sixtynine* with the pink colour, and now I am not sure whether the whole image is balanced.

[image: Logo]

Answer (score 4):

Given an opinion is the only answer there can be, I'll type an answer and not a comment.

**The word nine has no special significance, that I can see, and is too faint**

For me the pink "nine" is much to faint, and both because of the opacity, and maybe the colour, I hardly notice it at all.

I see no special significance concerning the word "nine" to the brand, so I see no reason why it should be in pink.

**Other problems**

I also find the cursive lettering very light (in weight), lacking in impact and legibility - How will this mark stand up to smaller renderings... Facebook icons etc?

The descender on the "y" visually clashes with the tagline as well I think.

Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Opinions: Too sparse, nine looks out as an add-on. Try this:

[image]

Comment: But how to explain "S" ON the symbol?

Comment: @Krii Why would you need to explain it? It balances the amount of text on either side of the heart better, making the entire logo look more balanced. It doesn't need any additional explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Without a proper brief about the brand is a little hard to give an objective opinion. But based on the type of business, I would recommend type that works well in small scales.

I assume you will apply this logo in small tags, gift packages and social media branding. Experiment printing the logo in a one inch high size and half inch high to see if it's still recognisable, and making some variations that use only the mark, as to position the mark and not the whole logo. This is useful when having this type of brands, since you can use the mark for little details the whole logo is not suitable for. (I really like the heart + keyhole idea!)

Also, remember contrast is used to attract attention to a certain element in the composition, and here, the color black has more weight. If you want to attract attention to the "nine" part, you might choose to change the font or make it a little bit more bold in relation to the other words, but color is not working out for you here. It also distracts from the mark (which is what you should try to emphasise and imprint in the customer's mind).

Experiment with separating the mark from the type and see what happens. If it's a luxury brand, sometimes adding negative space gives it a more balanced look. (Adding some letterspacing to the tagline will make it look cleaner, too).

Hope this helps! And keep up the good work!

Comment: Thank you very much for your great comment! Much appriciate!

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to add brand color in the initials of both words. And keep it bold or use some other Font.

Comment: You mean pink colour?

Comment: Yes. I think pink is the brand color. In order to make it more attractive in the middle of room and sixtynine have anything, which can replicate jewelry. Logo should be able to speak about what is the specific brand all about. 

Also if you wish to continue with the same color(Pink) tweak the font style.